# How can load IMDB Movie information using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code to get IMDB movies  information 
I have a site http://microdownload.ir to download free movies.

For information of series of movies i need to use IMDB API and i used this below code but its refresh my pages and post my article before complete that so i need to get information with Ajax i used following code

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Get IMDB Info</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <form method="post">
      Address : <input type="text" name="url" size="50"   placeholder="Example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1340138" dir="ltr"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Get">
    </form>
  </center>
  <br><br>
  <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    if(empty(!$_POST['url'])){
        echo '<div dir="ltr">';
        function IMDB ($url){
            preg_match("/tt\\d{7}/i", $url, $Id);
            $Get = file_get_contents('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i='.$Id[0]);
            $json = json_decode($Get,true);
            return $json;
        }

        $Response = IMDB($_POST['url']);
        if(!$Response){
            die ('خطا!');
        }
        echo "Title: ".$Response['Title'].'<br>'.
        "Year: ".$Response['Year'].'<br>'.
        "Rated: ".$Response['Rated'].'<br>'.
        "Released: ".$Response['Released'].'<br>'.
        "Runtime: ".$Response['Runtime'].'<br>'.
        "Genre: ".$Response['Genre'].'<br>'.
        "Director: ".$Response['Director'].'<br>'.
        "Writer: ".$Response['Writer'].'<br>'.
        "Actors: ".$Response['Actors'].'<br>'.
        "Plot: ".$Response['Plot'].'<br>'.
        "Language: ".$Response['Language'].'<br>'.
        "Country: ".$Response['Country'].'<br>'.
        "Awards: ".$Response['Awards'].'<br>'.
        "Poster: ".$Response['Poster'].'<br>'.
        "Metascore: ".$Response['Metascore'].'<br>'.
        "imdbRating: ".$Response['imdbRating'].'<br>'.
        "imdbVotes: ".$Response['imdbVotes'].'<br>'.
        "imdbID: ".$Response['imdbID'].'<br>'.
        "Type: ".$Response['Type'].'<br>'.
        "Response: ".$Response['Response'].'<br>'.
        '</div>'
        ;


    }
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Its work fine but
I want to Receive data with AJAX ( without reload page) to my `<p></p>` tags
It mean when i click to get data, my data set to `<p></p>` tags automatic

Comment: can you explain bit more about last portion of question.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: @dipak-chavda for example i need to put imdb link to input box and press the GET button then get information from api with ajax (witout reload page) and desplay to Separate inputs for ex one of input for name another to language and more ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pls try this :-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imdbInfoForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var arr = $('#imdbUrl').val().match(/tt(\d+)/);
        var imdbId = arr[0];
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + imdbId,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').html('Title: ' + data.Title + '<br>' + 'Year: ' + data.Year + '<br>' + 'Rated: ' + data.Rated + '<br>' + 'Released: ' + data.Released + '<br>' + 'Runtime: ' + data.Runtime + '<br>' + 'Genre: ' + data.Genre + '<br>' + 'Director: ' + data.Director + '<br>' + 'Writer: ' + data.Writer + '<br>' + 'Actors: ' + data.Actors + '<br>' + 'Plot: ' + data.Plot + '<br>' + 'Language: ' + data.Language + '<br>' + 'Country: ' + data.Country + '<br>' + 'Awards: ' + data.Awards + '<br>' + 'Poster: ' + data.Poster + '<br>' + 'Metascore: ' + data.Metascore + '<br>' + 'imdbRating: ' + data.imdbRating + '<br>' + 'imdbVotes: ' + data.imdbVotes + '<br>' + 'imdbID: ' + data.imdbID + '<br>' + 'Type: ' + data.Type + '<br>' + 'Response: ' + data.Response + '<br>');

                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                if (console && console.log) {
                    console.log("Sample of data:", data.slice(0, 100));
                }
            });
    })
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Get IMDB Info</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <form id="imdbInfoForm" method="post" >
      Address : <input type="text" name="url" size="50"   placeholder="Example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1340138" dir="ltr"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Get">
    </form>
  </center>
   <div id="result">
        </div>
 
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</html>
```

Comment: You can find the working copy of above code in pastebin http://pastebin.com/JGwGckqJ

Comment: how can put this information to many input for example for name txtname for language txt language and ... @Samuel-J-Mathew

Comment: its work fine but does not work on wordpress because i do not khnow where is the best place for js files

Comment: @zolfaghari put the js in script tag in footer

Comment: are you sure that you are using same html and js

Comment: yes i am sure but my page stll refreshed on wordpress

Comment: this code worked fine when i put that to php file and run but did not working on wordpress

Comment: Where you put your js

Comment: i put the code on external address and its work fine on single php file but when add script to header or footer it not working

Comment: is there any way without click on any button just when put the link on textbox script run and get the information? it seams wordpress have a submit button and it not work with 2 submit input